# Swift 3 Collection subclass won't compile

Tags: swift, collections

I have a `Node` class in Swift that implements `Collection` so that each `Node` acts recursively as a collection of child nodes of the same type.

The problem is when I subclass `Node`, I still want the subclass to act as a collection of `Node`s, but Swift won't even compile when I try to iterate over an instance of the subclass `DerivedNode`, complaining that:

> `IndexingIterator<Node>` is not convertible to `IndexingIterator<DerivedNode>`.

I'm confused why it would be trying to do this. I don't care about iterating over `DerivedNode`s, they should continue to be iterated as `Node`s.

Interestingly, the compiler/editor knows they should be of type `Node` as the help popup shows the right type. But it still fails to compile for some reason.

[image]

Here's how I implemented the `Collection` protocol:

```
extension Node: Collection {
    public typealias Index = Int

    public var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public var endIndex: Int {
        return attributes.count
    }

    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return i + 1
    }

    public subscript(i: Int) -> Node {
        return attributes[i].value
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you've conformed to `Collection`? Are you using `Node` as your `Element`?

Comment: I haven't explicitly declared an `Element` anywhere. Am I supposed to do that?

Comment: I can't recreate a node that works this way. What is `attributes`? It seems to be `[Node]`, but `value` is also `Node`?

Comment: It's actually `[(name: String, value: Node)]` but the string is not important in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not declare an iterator, then Collection gives you one:

```
public func makeIterator() -> IndexingIterator<Self>
```

You don't want that one, though. You want `IndexingIterator<Node>`. So you need to provide your own `makeIterator()` method:

```
public func makeIterator() -> IndexingIterator<Node> {
    return IndexingIterator(_elements: self)
}
```

This requires calling an undocumented initializer for `IndexingIterator`. IMO that's a [bug in the stdlib](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4832). Creating an `IndexingIterator` by hand should be supported.

Comment: Ah thanks! The documentation I was reading didn't mention that method. I guess technically it isn't required if you're not subclassing, but arguably the default behavior doesn't make a lot of sense when you are.